# StyleBundle not Minifying the CSS files , but it only Bundles the files where it is not minifying

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, umbraco7

i dont have idea about the ASP.NET but i tried some blogs and addedd the dll files for minification Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization and WebGrease dll files.
i am trying to minify the CSS file but when i debug and see i cant see its minified but its only bundled

my Class file

```
using System.Web.Optimization;
using Umbraco.Core;

namespace MySolution.helpers
{
public class CustomEventHandler : IApplicationEventHandler
 {
        public void OnApplicationInitialized(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext) 
        { }
        public void OnApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext) 
        { }
        public void OnApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            RegisterStyles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            RegisterJavascript(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
        private static void RegisterStyles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundle/styles.css").Include(
                    "~/css/carousel.css" , "~/css/menu.css" , "~/css/blog.css" , "~/css/general.css"
                ) );  

                bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundle/ultradata-styles.css").Include(
                    "~/css/ultradata-styles.css"
                ) );       

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;


        }
        private static void RegisterJavascript(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/javascript.js").Include(
                    "~/scripts/*.js"
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

in the browser the files are not minified[image]

web config debug is false already

```
 <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" batch="false" targetFramework="4.6.2" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="50">
```

can any one help me what am i missing

and the CMS in umbraco i am calling like this

```
   @using System.Web.Optimization
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>@Umbraco.Field("pageName")</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="@Umbraco.Field("metaDescription")">
        <meta name="keywords" content="@Umbraco.Field("metaKeywords")">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">   

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/socialiconstyle.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstap/css/bootstrap3.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/iconfont.css">
         @Styles.Render("~/bundle/styles.css" , "~/bundle/ultradata-styles.css")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the `/bundle` path to the reserved paths of Umbraco in your web.config file:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/bundle" />
```